# Finding rate of change in direction of vector $v=i+j-K$ with $V(x,y,z)=5x^2+3xy+xyz$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, partial-derivative

I have the problem:

"suppose that over a certain region of space the electrical potential V is given by $V(x,y,z)=5x^2+3xy+xyz$.

Find the rate of change of potential at $P(3,4,5)$ in the direction of the vector $v=i+j-K$.

I tried:

$|v|=\sqrt{3}$

$u= \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{3}}$

$F_x=10x+3y+yz$

$F_y=3x+xz$

$F_z=xy$

$D_uf=\frac{10x+3y+yz}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{3x+xz}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{xy}{\sqrt{3}}$

$D_uf=\frac{30+12+20}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{9+15}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{12}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{74}{\sqrt{3}}$

But the answer is  $\frac{32}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Your calculation looks correct to me, so either the given answer is wrong or there’s an error in the problem statement.

Comment: Hmm alright. Thanks.